# How to have optimized compound select for a range defined criteria?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, query-optimization, subquery

I have in the code two selects, first randomly selecting any 20 sportsmen

```
db.Query("SELECT sp_no, first_name FROM sportsmen LIMIT ?,20", rand.Intn(100000))
```

Then for every returned sportsmen in a loop do another select from points table where published their results in different competitions

```
db.Query("SELECT max(point) FROM points WHERE sp_no =" + spNo)
```

In result I have 20 sportsmen with their first_name and highest points numbers.
I'm looking for optimisation of these selects to combine them into one for avoiding looping in a code and then measure performance.

How to have one select statement which returning first_name and their highest points?

Looks like it's combination compound selects, join and exists verification?

Thank you.

Comment: `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` makes little sense.

Comment: Ponder this: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random

Answer (score 1):

You could join a table expression with the second query, as in:

```
select
  x.sp_no, x.first_name, max(point) as max_points
from (
  select sp_no, first_name
  from sportsmend 
  order by sp_no
  limit ?, 20
) x
join points p on p.sp_no = x.sp_no
group by x.sp_no, x.first_name
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try aggregating by `sp_no`, and ordering randomly:

```
SELECT s.sp_no, s.first_name, MAX(p.point) AS max_point
FROM sportsmen s
INNER JOIN points p
    ON s.sp_no = p.sp_no
GROUP BY s.sp_no, s.first_name
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 20;
```

Note that this approach completely handles all the heavy lifting directly in MySQL.  You app code should only have to execute the above query and fetch the result set.

Comment: Thank you for comment. Perhaps it wasn't clear, the data are in two tables connected through sp_no column as key. First_name is in sportsmen table and points itself are in points table.